# MS Teams: Disable notification for General

Tags: chat

In MS Teams, is it possible to disable receiving notifications in my Activity tab whenever someone mentions `@General` in a channel?

Answer (score 0):

Try Unfollowing the channel.

I think it depends on your admin set up the Team, but for me, I don't get Notifications if I don't Follow the Channel. It will just bold the Channel in the list.